# Helping Understand a for-each loop in java

Tags: java

So, basically, I am creating a method to check application numbers in my array 'applications' and this method accepts a parameter to check that particular application number and compares it to the application numbers in the list.

The code:

```
public boolean hasApplicationNumber(int number) {
    if (number <= 0 ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("bad number");   
    }

    for (ApplicationData current : applications) {
        if (number == current.getApplicationNumber() ) {    
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

JUnit test for checking the application number:

```
public void shouldHaveApplicationNumber1() {
    University westGeorgia = new University("West Georgia");
    ApplicationData student1 = new ApplicationData(1, 4.0, 100);
    westGeorgia.addApplication(student1);
    assertEquals(true, westGeorgia.hasApplicationNumber(1));
}
```

My code is failing this JUnit test and returning "false" instead of "true."

However, I can change the return values in my "hasApplicationNumber" method to true (at the very bottom of the method) and this test will pass, but another test I have (that doesn't allow the list to exceed 10) will return "true" when it is supposed to be "false" and causing that to fail (I didn't include that test because it is very similar to the one I have already provided -- just "1" is changed to "10" and the "true" is changed to "false").

I'm starting to think that either: my test is being ignored by the Java compiler, or my for-each loop is running correctly and returning "true" but since I have that lingering false at the very end, it may be declaring the thing false no matter what.

I may just be overthinking this, but I'm not sure how else to modify this for-each loop in the method I wrote. Any help on straightening this out will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried debugging? You can place a breakpoint to pause execution and take a look what happens step by step in your IDE even while executing unit tests.

Comment: What happens when you debug the code?

Comment: The simplest explanation should be considered first: that no entry in ```applications``` has the number you're looking for.  Is the constructor of ApplicationData correct?

Comment: Hello, I'm unsure of how to directly reply to comment threads, but as a disclaimer, this is a school project I am working on and the tests were written by faculty. We were explicitly told not to change the unit tests. Also, I ran the debug (I'm new to eclipse IDE) and what information should I be looking for to debug the algorithm?